# How do I copy styles in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I want to have efficient way to create numbered document. I haven't created numbered list before edition (I update this during edition).

I want to copy style #1 (where I number everything as 1., 2., and so on) to obtain style #2 with subnumbering (example 1.1., 1.2., 1.3. so on).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** After noticing your comment, I'm posting the general way. But please refer to external sources such as the given linked guide because an extensive explanation is filling several pages.

In general, if you want your own (multilevel) numbered list, the way would be:

1. Go to the "Home"-tab. In the "Paragraph"-section you can find the symbol for general multileveled lists like shown below.

   [image]
2. From the dropdown that's opening, choose "Define new List Style" (NOT new Multilevel list as this won't allow you to control the style).
3. Set the general properties for each of the levels to your liking. This is the very extensive part, so I'm refering to external resources as said before.
4. In general, you can have a different formatting for each level. For example, when you click on the "Format"-dropdown in the bottom left of the window, then select "Numbering". In the opening window, you can again click on the "More"-button in the bottom left to see all available options. As you can see by then, that's a LOT. Pay special interest to the "Link level to style"-dropdown if you want to have it working with TOCs as it must be linked to a style then.
5. I would recommend testing around accompanied by some guides in a separate test document for quite some time.
6. After you're done with defining your List style, you can access your style by clicking on the same dropdown you used for configuring it initially and then choosing from the available styles.
7. Subnumbering usually would still be handled by indentations. An easy way to do this is by clicking on the left and right arrow buttons that can be seen in the previous image right next to the dropdown.
8. If configured correctly, this will also work with automatically generated TOCs (you most likely have to adjust your TOC style then - marking the TOC.

Finally, some guides I would recommend for reading further:
[Excellent blog post from Shauna Kelly, MVP](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html?p=1768)
[Another blog post. Would recommend the first one, but again from a MVP.](https://officesmart.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/how-to-create-a-multilevel-list-in-a-word-document/)

---

Not sure, I'm getting quite what you want, but from my understanding you don't need a custom style for that.

Do you want something like this?
[image]

Of course that's a table of contents and not the actual content but that's your most important gain later - you can easily create such stuff if the preparation is good.

If that is all, all you need to do is:

1. Properly format your headings (not even necessary but recommended). Go to the "References"-tab, then click on "Add Text" in the top left ribbon area and select your Heading level.
2. Per default, this won't create numbered headers. However, if you don't have too much, I would do this simply over the "Home"-tab. Click on the symbol for numbered lists and at the bottom you can find "Change list level". Choose your wanted level from there. If your headings are consistent formatted, Word should take it over.

Of course, if your document is large, this might become tedious after some time.
In a case like that it actually might be helpful to create a custom header style, but that is more complex and I'm not convinced it's really needed in your case.

Comment: Can you show that:
,,Of course, if your document is large, this might become tedious after some time. In a case like that it actually might be helpful to create a custom header style, but that is more complex and I'm not convinced it's really needed in your case. "

Comment: See my edit above, although there's way more to it as I'm pointing out.